# Convert stream array of primitives to a stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

1. Why `Stream.of(arr)` returns a `Stream<short[]>` instead of `Stream<Short>` ?

   ```
   void f(short... arr){
       Stream<short[]> s = Stream.of(arr);
   }
   ```
2. How to convert `short[]` to `Stream<Short>`?

Answer (score 3):

When using `Stream.of(T... values)`, `T` must be a reference type not a primitive, type. `short` is a primitive type, whereas `short[]` is a reference type, so `Stream.of(shortArray)` gives you a `Stream<short[]>` as you have noticed.

One way to convert a `short[]` to a `Stream<Short>` is

```
Stream<Short> stream = IntStream.range(0, shortArray.length).mapToObj(i -> shortArray[i]);
```

However, I would question why you are using `short` at all.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `Short` doesn't make part of number wrapper classes that have their own Stream class (such as `IntStream` or `LongStream`).
So you should write more code.

You could for example use `mapToObj()` to box `short` to `Short` :

```
short[] shorts = ...;
Stream<Short> shortStream = IntStream.range(0, shorts.length)
                                     .mapToObj(i -> shorts[i]);
```